# crontab xinput returns empty results

Tags: bash, scripts, touchpad, cron, xinput

I made a file `/root/startup.sh` (I am on Ubuntu with Gnome 3.22.3 with root access) with the following contents:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=":0"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
SHELL="/bin/bash"

$(/usr/bin/xinput list > /root/Desktop/output.txt)
```

and I have put this line in the `crontab -e` file:

```
* * * * *  /bin/bash /root/startup.sh
```

but after a minute when the file `output.txt` is created and when I open it it is empty and there is no contents in it.
Why?

Comment: Are you putting it in you user's crontab, or root's? My guess is it's unable to connect to the X server. First I suggest removing the command substitution `$( . . . )` and redirecting errors to the file as well `/usr/bin/xinput list > /root/Desktop/output.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @steeldriver checkout the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many articles on web, so many questions and answers about this issue but non of them have notified me of this silly mistake:

```bash
export DISPLAY=":0"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
export SHELL="/bin/bash"
```

This should be used instead the 3 lines in my question.
I should have added `export` before them.
And it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you also need to set the XAUTHORITY variable.

```
export XAUTHORITY=/home/<user>/.Xauthority
```

As you are starting your script as root via cron, likely the root user does not have a .Xauthority file. But because you ARE root in the cron session, you can use the one from your regular user.